# First call to TextSelection.GotoLine fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a VS extension. Upon selecting some "result" in a "results list" panel, I am opening (or setting focus to) the related file in the source editor and scroll to the associated line and select it.

Strangely, the first call always fail in a way: scroll is bad. Instead of having the selected line in the middle of the visible text area as usual, the selected line is on the line before the first visible one (hence not visible).

All other subsequent calls work as expected...

In case there is some bad initial state, I tried to move the cursor before (using PageUp, PageDown, EndOfDocument...) but none worked.

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PS_ResultsList resultsList = (DataContext as PS_ResultsList);
    PS_Result selectedItem = resultsList.SelectedItem;

    // ...

    // Open related file when applicable
    string replacedFile = "some/path/hacking/for/debug";
    string filePath = selectedItem.filePath;

    // ...

    if (File.Exists(replacedFile))
    {
        DTE2 dte2 = PS_Package.Instance.GetService2(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
        var itemsOperations = dte2.ItemOperations;
        itemsOperations.OpenFile(replacedFile, Constants.vsViewKindCode);

        var textSelection = dte2.ActiveDocument.Selection as TextSelection;
        var line = selectedItem.function.lineNum;
        var col = selectedItem.function.colNum;

        textSelection.GotoLine(line, true);
    }
}
```

I would expect the first call to work as all others... Any idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: adding more details**

The results list:

```
    class PS_ResultsList : ObservableCollection<PS_Finding>
    {
        public PS_Finding SelectedItem { get; set; }
    }
```

The declaration in the XAML:

```
<UserControl ...
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="PS_ResultsList_TWC">
    <DataGrid
            SelectionMode="Single"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        ...
```

Filling up the results list: the results list is hosted into a Tool Window pane

```
    class PS_ResultsList_TW : ToolWindowPane
    {
        // ...

        public void SetResultsList(PS_ResultsList resultsList)
        {
            PS_ResultsList_TWControl resultsList_TWControl =
                Content as PS_ResultsList_TWControl;
            resultsList_TWControl.DataContext = resultsList;
        }
    }
```

**Edit: reduced example**

I have created a sample VSIX project with a Custom Command. I have hooked the following to the command:

```
        private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\some\path\to\some\file.cpp";

            MessageBox.Show("Opening file: " + filePath);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                DTE2 dte2 = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
                var itemsOperations = dte2.ItemOperations;
                itemsOperations.OpenFile(filePath, Constants.vsViewKindCode);

                var textSelection = dte2.ActiveDocument.Selection as TextSelection;
                textSelection.GotoLine(51, true);
            }
        }
```

It makes no difference if the file is local or on the network. For the line number I just make sure my example file has enough lines for the requested line to be displayed in the middle of the screen.

Reproduction steps:

- Start VS: no file open
- Select menu Tools > My Command: file opens and goto line fails (line is hidden)
- Close the file and open any other one
- Select menu Tools > My Command: file opens and goto line succeeds (line is visible in the middle of the screen)
- Close all files
- Select menu Tools > My Command: file opens and goto line fails (line is hidden)

Conclusion: goto line fails when opening the *first* file.

Comment: Do you use the Tool Window Item template? I'm not sure what the "result list" panel is, could you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) if possible.

Comment: Let me try to provide a bit more details. Regarding your question, please note that the binding works correctly, it is more on opening a file where GotoLine behaves strangely on the first time. The bad thing is that the first time is very visible will make the extension look buggy...

Comment: Hard to guess what a PS_Result might be, but I'd guess that its function.lineNum is the line number in the source code.  The GotoLine() method requires the line number in the *selection*, starting at 1.

Comment: Hi Hans! Thanks for your answer. Your guess is correct about PS_Result. I don't understand exactly your comment about the line number in the "selection". Indeed, doc says "Moves to the beginning of the indicated line and selects the line if requested". While I open a file, I would expect no selection, or at least selection being on the very first character with 0 length. How does it explain why only the first call would fail while all others would succeed, no matter opening a new file or setting focus to a new one? What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? I tried to reproduce your issue, it may take some time before I figure it out:(

Comment: Hi Lance! Thanks for your reply. Though incomplete, what I provided is the part of the real code, that seems to me related to the issue: open/focus file and select line #line upon selecting a "result". It would be much too big for here if I provided the whole thing. I will try to create a reduced example, hoping that it will still reproduce the issue...

Comment: Hi Lance! I submitted a reduced example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Stephane Thanks for the reproducing steps. I haven't notice the notivation until now. I will check your example later and try to locate the cause. I will try to give the reply tomorrow:)

Comment: I've tried, but after click the button it shows "object reference not set to an object" :( It might be something i do wrong. But for now I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: @Lance: Thanks. As I now have a very small reduced example, would it help if I send a zip to you?

Comment: @Stephane Yes, it would be of much help if you can share a simple sample(deleting the core code and it should build successfully).

Comment: @Lance: zip file available here (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/677405ee9eb039b208c80c6fe4d1fa2e20190614134048/265c9ff52e8a8c3d4b16ef55927c8e8320190614134048/38b1a8). It is just a brand new solution where I added a new custom command and replaced the command callback. Copy .\Resources\test.cpp into C:\TEMP. Build and run. Close any open file before. Select menu Tools > OpenFile and GotoLine. GotoLine will fail (line will be hidden above the 1st visible line). Open any file and rerun command. GotoLine will succeed (display line in the middle of the screen).

Comment: @Stephane Sorry for the delay. I will check it later. Thx for your sample to reproduce:)

Comment: @Stephane Hi friend, have you tried your extension in other developer's machine. I tried it many times but can't reproduce the issue. For example: In my side, when I start VS, click the GoToLine button with start page on, the go to line succeeds. Close all files, succeeds again.! Trying updating the VS to latest 15.9.13 and build it again to check if the issue persists, also make sure you have much more than 51 lines in the file.

Comment: @Lance: Thanks for your reply. Of course I only test with files having more than 51 lines ;-) I will try on a another developer's machine... On my side, the problem is really systematic, not sporadic... Also BTW I have got VS 2017 15.3.3. We don't have VS 2019 available right now. Is there a 2017 version more recent than 15.3.3?

Comment: @Stephane Update 15.3.3 to 15.9.13 and check if it helps. I tried your sample in this version and it works well :)

Comment: @Lance: I could update to 15.8.2. Behavior is better but still strange: now when opening the first file, gotoline set the selected line on the last visible line in the editor instead of the invisible line just before the first visible one. But are there any workarounds so that the selected line goes in the middle of the editor, like in all the other cases. It would be more consistent ;-)